# Get border color with jQuery in IE with .css()

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer, border

There is a problem getting border color of the clicked element in Internet Explorer.

```
$("#clickme").click(function() {
    alert($(this).css('border-color'));
});
```

Here is jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dS7mc/
It works in chrome but it doesn't work in IE10.

Any ideas how to make it work with both? Also changing to "border" only, in chrome it gives me `2px solid rgb(0, 0, 0)` but in Ie i still get empty alert.

PS. Yes, I've tried "borderColor". Also doesn't work in IE

Comment: @dystroy he said it gives an empty alert

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this ..Works on IE8

```
$("#clickme").click(function() {
    $('body').append($(this).css('border-top-color'));
});
```

[image]

## [*jsFiddle*](http://jsfiddle.net/mohammadAdil/dS7mc/31/)

Also,
Colors are returned by browsers in a different way FireFox, Safari and Chrome return them as `rgb()` values and `IE` returns them exactly like you set them in your `CSS` even when you use the shorthand notation (`#f00` vs `#ff0000`) and Opera always returns the color as `hexidecimal` with 6 digits

Answer (score 7):

This is because in Internet Explorer there is no `border-color`. The property gets renamed to border-*pos*-color:

```
border-top-color: #000000;
border-right-color: #000000;
border-bottom-color: #000000;
border-left-color: #000000;
```

The same applies to `border-width` and `border-style` (`border-left-width`, etc.). In order to pull the border color (assuming all 4 are the same), you'd use:

```
$(this).css('border-top-color');
```

Equally to pull the `border-width` or `border-style` (again assuming all 4 are equal) you'd use:

```
$(this).css('border-top-width');
$(this).css('border-top-style');
```

You can find which style properties an element has with IE's *F12 developer tools*:

[image: IE Dev Tools]

Answer (score 2):

similar to Mohammad Adil:

```
$("#clickme").click(function() {
    var Bcolor = $(this).css("border-left-color");
    alert(Bcolor);
});
```

you have to spec each side

Answer (score 1):

try regular js

```
var clickme = $("#clickme")[0];
    clickme.addEventListener('click', function() {
    alert(clickme.style.borderColor)
    }, false)
```

Comment: Well, sorry to say that, but i get empty alert even in Chrome. You could try setting up jsfiddle.

Comment: works for me locally on chrome and firebug but not on fiddle now that's odd